# Notification system using SpringBoot/WebFlux with React.js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have implemented notification system in SpringBoot using WebFlux, below is my sse endpoint

```
@GetMapping(path = "/backoffice/sse/notifications")
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> sse()
{
    return this.sseNotificationService.subscribe();
}
```

And here is the implementation of SSENotificationService

```
@Component
public class SSENotificationService
{

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SSENotificationService.class);

private final Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> notificationFlux;

private final NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

private final UserService userService;

public SSENotificationService(
    NotificationRepository notificationRepository,
    UserService userService
)
{
    this.notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
    this.userService = userService;
    notificationFlux = Flux.push(this::generateNotifications);
}

@Nonnull
private Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> keepAlive(
    @Nonnull Duration duration,
    @Nonnull Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> data,
    @Nonnull String id
)
{
    Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> heartBeat = Flux.interval(duration)
        .map(_ -> ServerSentEvent.<NotificationData>builder()
            .event("comment")
            .comment(STR."keep alive for: \{id}")
            .build())
        .doFinally(_ -> LOGGER.info("Heartbeat closed for id: {}", id));
    return Flux.merge(heartBeat, data);
}

@Nonnull
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> subscribe()
{
    var userIdOrSystem = userService.userIdOrSystem();
    return keepAlive(Duration.ofSeconds(7), notificationFlux, userIdOrSystem);
}

private void generateNotifications(@Nonnull FluxSink<ServerSentEvent<NotificationData>> sink)
{
    var userIdOrSystem = userService.userIdOrSystem();
    Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .flatMap(_ -> {
            var pendingNotifications = this.notificationRepository.pendingNotifications(userIdOrSystem);
            return Flux.fromIterable(pendingNotifications)
                .map(notificationData -> {
                    this.notificationRepository.updateNotificationStatus(notificationData.id());
                    return ServerSentEvent.<NotificationData>builder()
                        .id(notificationData.id())
                        .data(notificationData)
                        .event("message")
                        .build();
                });
        })
        .doOnNext(sink::next)
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            LOGGER.error("An error occurred while processing notifications: {}", throwable.getMessage());
            return Flux.empty();
        })
        .doFinally(signalType -> LOGGER.debug(signalType.toString()))
        .takeWhile(_ -> !sink.isCancelled())
        .subscribe();
}
}
```

This imlementation works fine when I test with postman,
[image]

But I'm having trouble handling notifications on client side with React.js, I have tried everything, but cannot receive events, sse.onopen function gets called when i call the endpoint, but onmessage won't work for some reason, any ideas why ?

Comment: Solved this by adding header "no-transform" for cache control to response, also sse.close wasn't working due to proxy configurations in webpack, so I also added 

"onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
          res.on('close', () => proxyReq.destroy());
        }"
to my webpack proxy configuration, and just a note you need to add it only for specific path (the one you open sse connection with)